# Java executable slows randomly once installed

Tags: java, performance, exe, lag

I made a Java application for a client that needs to be installed in the computer, the app connects to a SQL database in a server. When the app is in use runs normally until at a random moment it starts lagging despite no consult to the database is being done, something as simple as scrolling in the app gets slow and changing from frames gets really slow(maybe a minute or two when normally it takes half a second).

I read that the problem could be the Java version and that could be slowing the application, but after updating Java the app keeps lagging despite randomly and returning to normal randomly as well.

When the app is being used in Netbeans it runs with no problem and the code doesn't seem to be the problem because it works normally and it does what it's supposed to do.

Any idea of why the Java executable lags randomly when in Netbeans runs without problem?

Comment: What program did you use in order to create the `.jar`?

Comment: Track the memory usage while running the application to see if it is spiking.

Comment: Garbage Collection?

Comment: It could very well be garbage collection causing this. Use an app like JProfiler to figure out what may be the issue. If GC is being called too often, increase memory given to the app, and try to find the source of it, and resolve it.

Comment: If it is GC, you could also try running on a newer JVM or switching the GC algorithm. There have been several improvements to the GC in recent Java versions.

Comment: @Elijah Actually I forgot to say that I monitored the usage of the CPU and the RAM and I didn't see anything unusual, the CPU stayed under 5% and the RAM below 150mb (which is normal).

Comment: @Frontear Garbage Collector is called often, but even after closing the application it keeps lagging.

Comment: Are you testing both applications on the same machines? If not, you should test both the developer versions and release builds on the same machine. Make sure to use the same version

Comment: @GeorgeZ. The `.jar` was created by Netbeans, but the executable and installer was created using launch4j.

Comment: @Frontear I haven't, the computer they let me use for testing is almost a potato and it gets pretty slow some time that I haven't installed an IDE to try the developer version, but I'll do it tomorrow when they open again and I can go.

Comment: Are you running the app on your development system where you say you have no issue running it under NetBeans? Does it run as an app fine on your system and poorly on another system?

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware/local issue, nothing to do with your program, but the computer you have tested on. Instead, try running your tests on the same machine

Comment: @Elijah Yes when I test the application on my computer runs smoothly, actually they allowed me to use another computer they weren't using(a gaming one) so I could fix some errors from the database connection and using the developer version of the code on Netbeans on a computer that wasn't mine, it run perfectly with no lag. That's why I believe that the problem comes from the executable.

Comment: My experience in the past with such performance issues usually were caused by Virus Scanners and port restrictions. We had a system that was blazing fast on all of our equipment. When we installed it on the client system we spent 1/2 the day trying to figure out what it was. We had them temporarily shut off all of their security restrictions on the box and limit the restrictions on their network and it worked as it should have. Point is it was external factors that deal with network protection that may be killing things.